# How can I find the index of the highest value in a vector, defaulting to the greater index if there are two "greatest" indices?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have been using `std::max_element(vec)`, but from what I can tell, it returns the smallest index if two "greatest" indices are equal.

Example:

```
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2, 5};
```

`std::max_element(v)` would reference `v[4]`, but for the purposes of my project I need it to reference `v[8]` instead. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: `max_element` with `reverse_iterator`s? (Are you writing pseudo-code, or using Eric Niebler's range library already? There is no currently-Standard `std::max_element` taking just a `std::vector`.)

Comment: You can search on from the first result you got.

Comment: @BoBTFish thanks! I'll look into this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this

```
max_element(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
```

to refer to the greatest index of the greatest value.

For example,

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2, 5};
    *max_element(v.rbegin(), v.rend())=-1;
    for (auto i: v) cout << i << ' ';
}
```

produces output

```
1 2 3 4 5 3 3 2 -1
```

The method mentioned above returns a reverse iterator, as pointed out by @BoBTFish. To get a forward iterator, you could do this:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2, 5};
    reverse_iterator < vector <int> :: iterator > x (max_element(v.rbegin(), v.rend()));
    vector <int> :: iterator it=--x.base(); // x.base() points to the element next to that pointed by x. 
    *it=-1; 
    *--it=0; // marked to verify 
    for (auto i: v) cout << i << ' ';
}
```

produces output

```
1 2 3 4 5 3 3 0 -1 
              ^
```

It can be seen that the iterator `it` is a forward iterator.

Comment: Bear in mind this gives you a `reverse_iterator` to the element, which you may want to convert back to the "proper" iterator type (`std::vector::iterator`). I think it would improve your answer if you show how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

It's very easy to make your own function:

```
/* Finds the greatest element in the range [first, last). Uses `<=` for comparison.
*
* Returns iterator to the greatest element in the range [first, last).
* If several elements in the range are equivalent to the greatest element,
* returns the iterator to the last such element. Returns last if the range is empty.
*/

template <class It>
auto max_last(It first, It last) -> It
{
    auto max = first;
    for(; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*max <= *first) {
            max = first;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: You could make this follow the style of the standard algorithms by taking a `Comparator` that follows a strict weak ordering, then using `if(!cmp(*first, *max)) { max = first; }`. Although the standard algorithms typically have a version not taking a comparator, and defaulting to `<` (which is not quite the same as defaulting to `std::less<T>`, which may be specialised).

Comment: A type is more likely to support `<` than `<=`. And `<=` can be implemented in terms of `<`: `a <= b` is equal to `(a < b) || (!(a < b) && !(b < a))`. So you don't necessarily need to require `<=`.